# React to redux state changes by executing function inside of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently trying to implement `redux` to my react-app for the first time.

I created a reducer, connected react with redux and setup an action within component A - so far so good. But how do I listen to a state change inside of component B?

Something like this:

```
changes.subscribe(value => {
   if (value === 1) {
       this.runSpecificFunction();
   } 
});
```

In other words, **I want to subscribe to the changes, and react to them by executing some functions** inside of component B. How can I do so?

What I've got so far for Component B - the receiving component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        nav: state.navigation
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(CartHolder));
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    navigation: 0 // inactive
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'START_NAVIGATION':
            return {
                navigation: action.value
            };
        case 'STOP_NAVIGATION':
            return {
                navigation: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: You don't need to call `subcscribe` anywhere. Every component that is wrapped in `connect` is subscribed to your store and will re render everytime your store changes

Comment: What is `changes`? If it's a redux store then why is the handler function expecting a parameter to be passed to it? If you want a component to do something based on state changes then just connect, componentDidUpdate and componentDidMount or useSelector with effect for functional components using hooks

Comment: @azium `will re render everytime your store changes`: incorrect, it will re render if what mapStateToProps returns changes, if you use useSelector it will re render when what the selector returns changes. Since the OP has a mapStateToProps that returns a new object every time it will re render every time anything in the state changes.

Comment: @HMR `changes` is solely a property I just made up - how I imagined it to work. How can I fire a function on redux state change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any state change (redux based or not) will re-render your child component. So using the `useEffect` hook should fit your use case (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Something like this in your example :

```
const CartHolder = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    myCallbackFunction(nav);
  }, [nav]);

  return (...);
};
```